# How do you say "to take a field trip"?

Tags: phrase-requests

'Vojaĝi' does not adequately express the idea of an education trip one takes for school. I have some ideas but wanted to know if there was a more mainstream translation that wouldn't confuse the literal use of 'field':

- Iri en kampa vojaĝo
- Iri en kampvojaĝo
- Iri en ekskurso de lernejo
- Edukvojaĝi

Dankon!

Comment: I would go for either of the two bottom ones. Don't forget that people with a different native language might not understand what 'field' means here, and could interpret it as an agricultural journey. It's always better to translate the meaning rather than the words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, *lerneja ekskurso* is the mainstream translation when a high school class is involved, as in *mi iros en/al lerneja ekskurso* or *mi partoprenos lernejan ekskurson.* *Lerneja tendaro* is also used for a high school camp.

For scientists and researchers, with or without their students, the best expression depends on the type of activity: I’ve heard both *esplorvojaĝo* and *surloka esplorado* for linguists but for, say, botanists or geologists, *esplor-ekspedicio* might be better, as it conveys the idea of wild, little known, possibly uncharted territory. Archaeologists embark upon *fosad-kampanjoj,* and so on.

As Oliver Mason pointed out in his comment, the particular meaning that “field” has here is not conveyed by *kampo.*

Comment: So the full phrase might be, _iri en lerneja ekskurso_ ?

Comment: I edited my answer with example phrases.